# JDBC Batch update Locking the Table and not responding for 7 million Records

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

We are facing an issue while updating the table records through a JDBC batch update. The table is locked and the execution is stuck while invoking the `excecuteBatch()` method. This table contains 7 Million records. Table scanning is taking more time. Please advise any best practice is for resolving this issue. `PRODUCT_CODE` is the primary constraint of the table

```java
  PreparedStatement ps = null;
           FacadeCommonManagerBean facadeCommonManagerBean = new FacadeCommonManagerBean();
          String sqlQuery = "UPDATE TABLENAME SET SBU_CODE=?,......... WHERE PRODUCT_CODE=? "; 
           try (Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection()) {
            ps = connection.prepareStatement(sqlQuery);
            final int batchSize = 5000;
            int count = 0;
            if (productCol != null)
                for (ProductValue productValue : productCol) {
                    ps.setString(1, productValue.getSbuCode());     
                    ps.setString(2, productValue.getProdLineId());
                                        ............................................
                                        .........................................
                                   }
......................................
                                         ps.addBatch();
                    
                    if (++count % batchSize == 0) {
                        
                        try {
                            ps.executeBatch();
                        } catch (SQLException e) {
                            log.error(ERROR_STRING_ONE, e);
                        }
                    
                    }
                }
           }
            try {
                ps.executeBatch(); // insert remaining records
                
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                log.error(ERROR_STRING_ONE, e);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Have you tested the stuff using

   - smaller batch size (100, 500, 1000)
   - a similar table with less number of rows (20000)
2. Please note that the network package size was in former days 32k
   so when a Batch consist of more then 32k you may get stuck -
   you could check this by doing a network trace - since thin
   drivers do not use Oracle Network, you need to use OCI thick driver
   to configure tracing parameters using sqlnet.ora
   to see whats going on on server an client side.
3. Try to implement a PLSQL procedure and pass the array to it and execute.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I already tried different batch sizes. The data for insertion collected from an excel file upload functionality. Only this table showing issues while updating the existing data. if we are uploading an excel file with 2 records for updating then also issue updating is not working. Fresh insertion of excel data is working quickly.100k will upload within 15 minutes by using batch insert.